# Uknown system errno 56

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm getting the following error when I try to run "grunt watch":

```
N:\github>grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: watch Unknown system errno 56

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: watch Unknown system errno 56

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: watch Unknown system errno 56
```

This is on windows 7 and the version of grunt is 0.4.5

Node version is 0.10.29 and grunt-contrib-watch is on 0.6.1

Comment: Which version of Node.js and grunt-contrib-watch? It sounds like you may need to update to get the latest fixes.

Comment: Node is at 0.10.29. I ran npm install -g grunt-contrib-watch to ensure I was using the latest. It's at 0.6.1. Still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errno 56 is usually due to watching a readonly file system (https://www.npmjs.org/package/errno) is your N drive writeable to the user running the process?  If it's a windows shared drive, there could also be other issues at the OS level, they typically treat code-over-the-network as a potential attack vector ("they" being "Windows OS's").

Comment: How to solve the error message above, when running grunt watch on a windows shared drive (using samba)?
Thanks!